# How can i write a proper path to save files in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have made an application to save customer invoices in shared folder
so first in my desktop-pc I have created a folder and named as "PDFINVOICES" in D: drive.

and I have made that folder to accessible for everyone.
Folder right click->properties->sharing->advance sharing & also in security tab as well

and I have changed my application path as

//Original path

```
String path = "docs/" + pdfFilename;
```

//Changed path

```
String path = "file://172.21.1.91/PDFINVOICES/" + pdfFilename;
```

and when i run it, it gives an error
called

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\172.21.1.91\PDFINVOICES\222016-08-23.pdf (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Previously it worked nicely with original path.
After i changed it, it doesn't work.

Comment: is `PDFINVOICES` anywhere close to `docs`?

Comment: For a Windows-System that would be a UNC-Path. See [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html). You also may want to build your path using utility classes like `Paths`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quess but try:

```
String path = "\\\\172.21.1.91\\PDFINVOICES\\" + pdfFilename;
```

Comment: Nice to hear. It's been 5 years when i last used Java, apparently still in head. Please mark as accepted if it answered your question.