# How do i read an image file from my java application?

Tags: java

i have developed an invoice generate program.
each pdf invoice include an image on top left corner, when i run the application on someone else's machine(not the developed machine), it doesn't show the image on top left corner of the pdf.

this is how I read the image:

```
Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance("images/amadeus14.png");
```

This is my option 1

within the project i have created a package and inside it i have made a folder called image.
inside that folder i have put that image file and tried to access it in my program.

```
Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance("Resources/Images/HemasLogo.jpg");
```

this is my option 2 option

but it gives an error saying

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\businesssupport\Documents\NetBeansProjects\invoiceGenerator\Resources\HemasLogo.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Without more code we can only guess where you problem is. Maybe your image path is different?

Comment: i can't upload folders here? in my application folder, i have assigned image folder with the image i want. i'm just trying access that image?

Comment: Check with `System.getProperty("user.dir")` if the working path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your previous questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096841/how-can-i-write-a-propper-path-for-save-files-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099011/how-can-i-access-a-file-in-a-folder-using-java),

- you must know you're trying to read from current working directory (you can find it using `System.getProperty("user.dir"))` )
- It is not a webapp.
- You cannot use shared (FTP) folders

So, I can see 2 options:

1. to put the image inside a package before packing the application, then you will be able to read it from any computer without making any changes

   Check [Including Images with an executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488836/including-images-with-an-executable-jar)

2. Use a local folder. You will need to create a common folder for each installed computer, then manually copy the image on each computer, and read it like

   ```
    Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance("C:\\myApp\\images\\amadeus14.png");
   ```

Comment: In addition to this, if OP is using iText it's also useful to have a look at [this question about PDF images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742125/getting-image-from-drawable-and-adding-to-pdf-using-itext)